# Can't load System.Web.Cors assembly after call to Microsoft.Owin.Cors

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-assembly

When I check the `System.Web.Cors` assembly reference in the Solution Explorer, the `Version` is **5.2.3.0**. The `Specific Version` property is set to `False`. The path is to the local project bin folder. When checking the .dll properties from the File Explorer, the file's product version and file version. is also **5.2.3**.

My **Web.config**:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Cors" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

My **packages.config** (I think the troublesome assembly is `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`, but I included another one here with a similar name):

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Error is thrown on this line in **Startup.cs**

```
app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

Here is the full error:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException was unhandled by user code
  FileName=System.Web.Cors, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
  FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Cors, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///P:/project-z4a/project-z4a/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = P:\project-z4a\project-z4a\bin
Calling assembly : Microsoft.Owin.Cors, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: P:\project-z4a\project-z4a\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: D:\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Cors, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/*****/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/f8163156/5c96d267/System.Web.Cors.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/*****/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/f8163156/5c96d267/System.Web.Cors/System.Web.Cors.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///P:/project-z4a/project-z4a/bin/System.Web.Cors.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

  HResult=-2146234304
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Cors, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
  Source=Microsoft.Owin.Cors
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.get_AllowAll()
       at z4a_dsa.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) in P:\project-z4a\project-z4a\Startup.cs:line 23
  InnerException:
```

So, I can see it's expecting v5.0.0.0, but I can't see where where or why calling for this version.

I've done the following steps to debug this error. After each of the listed attempts, I cleaned, then rebuilt the project. The error hasn't changed after trying each of these steps.

- `Update-Package`
- `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`
- `Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`, then `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`
- `Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`, then `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors -Version 5.2.3`
- Downgraded `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` to `v5.0.0.0` via the Package Manager Window.

I'm not an expert in .NET yet, and this is the 4th occurrence of the same exact error with a different assembly each time, since I started a fresh empty project with `Web Api` checked. And I installed the `z4a-foundation-scaffold-auth` package into my project. I would definitely appreciate some explanation of my gaps in knowledge here!

**EDIT**: Used ILDASM.exe to look at `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` assembly. Found it specified `System.Web.Cors v5.0.0.0` in its manifest definition. I guess my question is now how to remedy this?

Comment: Check the other dependent DLL files with ILDASM.exe. there must be at least one dll file which requires System.Web.Cors v5.0.0.0

Comment: OK, so the `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` manifest requires `System.Web.Cors v5.0.0.0`. How can I address this?

Comment: Have you added an assembly binding redirect to your web.config for System.Web.Cors? Basically, just redirect all versions to whatever the latest that you installed into your main application. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I listed the binding redirect from my Web.config above, already. I think the problem is that the `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` assembly requires System.Web.Cors 5.0 but I don't have it installed. Would installing this in my GAC solve the problem? If so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Turns out **System.Web.Cors.dll** does not come from the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` package. It comes from the `Microsoft.AspNet.Cors` package.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Cors -Version 5.0.0
```

This resolved the immediate error.

In case you have a scenario in which you need two different versions of the **System.Web.Cors.dll**, I'd suggest this solution:

1. Using the Package Manager, change the version of `Microsoft.AspNet.Cors` to the version that `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` requests in its manifest definition.
2. Using the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio (run as admin), navigate to the package folder for the newly versioned `Microsoft.AspNet.Cors` where the *System.Web.Cors.dll** resides.
3. Run the following command: `gacutil -i System.Web.Cors.dll`.
4. Go back to the Package Manager and change `Microsoft.AspNet.Cors` back to the version you originally wanted.

This method simply pulls the desired version of the .dll file into your Solution's packages folder. Then you use `gacutil.exe` to add this version of the .dll to your Global Assembly Cache. Visual Studio probes for the desired .dll versions first in the GAC, then in your local project.

Comment: I had the same problem except the package was allready installed. I fixed it with `Update-Package –reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.Cors` after viewing your answer.

Comment: is there a download for the .dll-file? I can't use the nuGet package manager

Comment: @Caleb Faruki Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

run this command into PM (package manager)

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Cors -Version 5.2.3.0