# Exception could not load assembly Cors

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-assembly

I'm developing a webApi inside my app. I have a strange issue. I tried to do this project inside an independent console application and everything runs well. My problem is when I try to load that web api inside another big application. I'm getting this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

This is the class where I use it:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        HttpConfiguration configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
        configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "TestApi",
            routeTemplate: "test/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );
        app.UseWebApi(configuration);
    }
}
```

I debugged, and my problem is when I use the `app.UserCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)` function. I installed Microsoft CORS package using *Nuget* package manager and I tried to update it but still getting this error. I searched here [Can't load System.Web.Cors assembly after call to Microsoft.Owin.Cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467106/cant-load-system-web-cors-assembly-after-call-to-microsoft-owin-cors) but the solution is not working for me.

I have this app.config file:

```
  <runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="3.0.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Cors" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Maybe the problem is in System.Web.Cors? I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your config you say

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

that means, that you use Microsoft.Owin version 2.0.2.0
but some of your code (implementation of IAppBuilder i suppose) requres "Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"

If you use NuGet, upgrade package, If not - you should download 3.0.1.0 version, update reference and change config file

Comment: Thank you this solved my issue. I don't know why using nuget package manager messed my app.config files. I tried installing owin through command line and now that part is well written and working.