# Angular 2 Login using ASP.NET Identity Token

Tags: angular, cors, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

I'm working on an Angular 2 application that is making service calls to an ASP.NET Web API 2 service. In this service CORS has been enabled in the `WebApiConfig` like so:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ...

        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");

        config.EnableCors(cors);

        ...

    }
}
```

This has been working fine and I've hadn't had any problems with CORS. For example calling `/api/users` retrieves all the users successfully.

Now however I'm trying to use the .NET Identity Token for the login functionality which is giving me issues related to CORS. When calling the `/token` to perform a login in my `login.service.ts`:

```
loginUser(username: string, password: string) {
    let serviceURL = 'http://myurl/token';

    let body = 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password + '&grant_type=password';

    let headers: Headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    let options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers
    });

    return this.http.post(serviceURL, body, options)
        .map(res => this.extractData(res))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I get the following error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myurl/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.`

I'm finding this confusing for two reasons:

1. As mentioned above I'm not having CORS issues with any of the `/api` calls
2. When I enter the correct credentials the call is "successful" (i.e. `Status Code 200` but I get the error listed above.

I've looked at a lot of different articles with a similar implementation and I can't seem to find what's wrong with mine.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I've finally found the reason why this was happening. As highlighted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28571892/2312637) it seems that the `/token` endpoint is initialised before the `WebApiConfig` is and so any set up here would not enable CORS for the `/token` endpoint.

To enable it for this endpoint as well the following should be added in the `IdentityConfig.cs` `Create` function:

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
{

    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

    ...

}
```