# How can I expose the custom header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in WebApi.Cors - 5.2.2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.Net WebAPI application using:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Cors - 5.2.2
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors - 5.2.2
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi - 5.2.0
```

Please note I had some problems displaying the http address with stackoverflow so it might look a bit strange on this question:

I have set the following:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("`http://localhost:4181`", "*", "*", "X-Custom-Header"); 
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

and in my controller:

```
   [EnableCors(origins: "`http://localhost:4181`", headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "X-Custom-Header", SupportsCredentials = true)]
   [OverrideAuthentication]
   [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]
   [AllowAnonymous]
   [Route("ExternalLogin", Name = "ExternalLogin")]
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExternalLogin(string provider, string error = null)
```

- When I access the site with IE11 I can login to the site (Ajax login) the correct response is sent back but I don't see any customer headers saying Access-Control-Allow-Origin. IE accepts what came back and takes me to the next page.
- When I access the site with Chrome I can login to the site (Ajax login) the correct response is sent back but I don't see any customer headers saying Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Crome does not accept the resonse and even though there's a 200 code returned it does not go to the next page. Instead it gives this message in the console:

  XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:3048/Token`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '`http://localhost:4181`' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 502.

When I check with fiddler both the IE and the Chome calls return the correct access data from the login but Crome goes no further than displaying the console error message.

Comment: Why do you have ' surrounding the url in the enablecors attribute "`http://localhost:4181`",  remove it.

Comment: FYI, it's not necessary to call both EnableCors() _and_ decorate a controller with `[EnableCors]`. The former enables it globally.

Comment: Omar - That's just for the SO question. It kept giving me messages saying I could not include localhost link in the question. See my note at the top of the question explaining this. thanks

Comment: Richard - I did the decorate so I could include "SupportsCredentials = true". Is there a way that I can do that globally also? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line of code to GrantResourceOwnerCredentials, which will add the header to the response.

context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

Check my answer here [ASP.NET WEB API 2 OWIN Authentication unsuported grant_Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971190/asp-net-web-api-2-owin-authentication-unsuported-grant-type/21979279#21979279)

and my article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/742532/Using-Web-API-Individual-User-Account-plus-CORS-En), where you can find a working project with CORS enabled.

Comment: I did this but now I am getting a different message: A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true.

Comment: check the link that I've added to the answer, it shows how to enable CORS for Web API 2, and call the api from AngularJS client.

Comment: Thanks Omar. I will check out your article. I did one thing which was replace the "*" with my origin. But then now I get a message saying Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is ''. It must be 'true' to allow credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems setting

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Some browsers do not accept *, but requires the response to contain the domain name of the originating request, like this:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: stackoverflow.com

Therefore (and for security reasons): On the server, read the domain the request originates from, compare this against a whitelist, set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the domain the request originates from.